# Cookie with a background src is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

My jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("#background").on('submit' function(e) {
    var src = $("#background input").content();
    $.cookie("background",src);
});
});
```

My html:

```
<form id="background">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

When I submit the form it should update/place a cookie called background with the full src link of the image but this is not working for me

Working:

```
$(function() {
  $("#background").on('submit', function(e) {
      var src = $(this).find("input").val();
      $.cookie("background",src);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Anything in the console?

Comment: No but when I inspect the element with safari you can see all the installed cookies and on my site there just none installed

Comment: So haim770's answer is probably correct. I also notice that you're missing the `$` in front of the `("#background input")` selector.

Comment: @JasonP thanks for notice changed it, but still not working

Comment: And the $ sign in front of the ("#background") selector.

Comment: You're also missing a comma `,` after `on('submit'`.

Comment: @Sake I find it hard to believe that you don't have any errors in your console, since your code is full of syntax errors...

Comment: Oooh god, I'm sorry for wasting your time. It was made with too many syntax errors (sometimes it happens when your 15 and not know jQuery to good)